# How to run a single test in pytest using a complex custom id as a selector?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

A similar question is being asked here: [parametrize and running a single test in pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943470/parametrize-and-running-a-single-test-in-pytest).

My question is more complex, as I parametrize the test with custom `ids`:

```py
LIST_OF_PARAMS = [('A', 1, 'data1'), ('B', 2, 'data2'), ('C', 3, 'data3')]
@pytest.fixture(scope="session",
                params=LIST_OF_PARAMS,
                ids=[f"{key1}, {key2}" for key1, key2, _ in LIST_OF_PARAMS])
def data(self, request):
    return request.param

def test_foo(data):
    pass
```

The tests invoked with the ids removed are identified like that:

```
____________________ test_foo[data0] ____________________
____________________ test_foo[data1] ____________________
____________________ test_foo[data2] ____________________
```

This allows me to run a single test using the `-k` key:

```
python -m pytest -k "test_foo[data1]"
```

When I run pytest with custom `ids`, the identificators change:

```
____________________ test_foo[A, 1] ____________________
____________________ test_foo[B, 2] ____________________
____________________ test_foo[C, 3] ____________________
```

This no longer allows me to invoke a single test using `test_foo[data1]` key (which is expected and desired), but the invocation below doesn't work either:

```
python -m pytest -k "test_foo[B, 2]"
```

Pytest returns an error:

```
ERROR: Wrong expression passed to '-k': test_foo[B, 2]
```

Putting the expression into quotes doesn't help:

```
python -m pytest -k "test_foo['B, 2']"

AttributeError: 'KeywordMapping' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This example is artificial, in practice I have complex tuples as a parameter, and ids cannot be experessed as simple Python identificators. Anyway, pytest accepts these ids, and displays tests using the strings I provide. How should I specify the `-k` parameter to let pytest select the test using a complex custom identificator?

Comment: Why are you insisting on the coma, can't you use something like dash or underscore?

Comment: The data provided in LIST_OF_PARAMS has strings that contain dashes, underscores, etc.

Comment: You could replace them when constructing the ids?

Comment: I *could* use the ids like `test_foo[data1]`, but I don't want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is you can't achieve what you are looking for using a comma. Pytest uses a specific parsing pattern which can be found [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/main/src/_pytest/mark/expression.py#L88). This patterns allows for the following characters:

```
+
.
\\
/
-
_
```

Your ids must use one of the following otherwise it will not work. Take a look at how Pytest tests the parser [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/31c207a0b5171c8a28149189818075f3d4a883c9/testing/test_mark_expression.py#L138-#L195). Longer answer is you can modify that pattern within your environment to suit your needs, but it might have unintended consequences when running the code.